# Map query result to a case class

Tags: scala, slick

I have two case classes

```
case class Foo(id: int, foo: String)
```

and

```
case class Bar(id: Int, bar: String, fooId: Int)
```

that are mapped to tables in a standard way:

```
class FooTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Foo](tag, "FOO") {
   ...
}
```

finally I have two table queries  `val foos = TableQuery[FooTable]` and  `bars = TableQuery[BarTable]`

Now I want to define a multi-table query, say:

```
val fooBars = foo leftJoin bars on (_.id === _.fooId)
```

However, this returns me a list of tuples `(foo, bar)`. Is it possible to create a `case class FooBar(foo: Foo, bar: Bar)` and map somehow the result of `fooBars` query to a sequence of `FooBar`? Working with unnamed tuples becomes a nightmare (especially when I compose a bigger query using smaller building blocks)

Comment: `fooBars.map(tp => FooBar(tp._1, tp._2)`?

Comment: do as @EndeNeu has but, `tp=> FooBar(tp.tupled)`, that eliminates _._X the boilerplate.